Como saber cuantas capas y cuantas neuronas poner para una predicción lineal en Machine Learning Python TensorFlow Keras
Cordial saludo...
He estado estudiando redes neuronales por mi propia cuenta y me dispongo a tratar de resolver un ejercicio de regresión lineal ML por mi propia cuenta:
REPO:
https://github.com/felipedelosh/ColombianMarijuanaSeizurePredictionML
Con el dataset de todas las incautaciones de marihuana en CO:
https://www.datos.gov.co/Seguridad-y-Defensa/INCAUTACIONES-DE-MARIHUANA/g228-vp9d
Con los registros de FECHA (YYYY & MM) CÓDIGO DE MUNICIPO y Target: "Cantidad de KG de Marihuana incautada"
Estoy tratando de predecir un modelo de machine learning y he intentado con las siguientes configuraciones:

La cosa es que no tengo ni la más mínima idea de como saber cual es la arquitectura para solucionar este problema... me gustaría que alguien me explicara lo siguiente:
La cantidad de datos de entrada son +900000
La cantidad de municipios son 1043
1 - Como sé que arquitectura usar?
2 - La arquitectura que mejor resultados me ha dado es:
model = Sequential() model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

Como se puede ajustar los epochs y learning rate para perfeccionar esa arquitectura?
3 - Como saber usando los valores LOSS, MSE, R2 como modificar la arquitectura para acercarse a la respuesta?
